# Asp.net c#, after deserialized, id property set 0 always

Tags: c#, asp.net

I pass a json format data to controller, like below

```
test_json = "[{\"id\":85,\"name\":\"AAA\"},{\"id\":86,\"name\":\"BBB\"}];
```

but after deserialized, id property set 0 always.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
IList<myObj> myObjs = serializer.Deserialize<IList<myObj>>(test_json);
```

myObjs contains 2 list, but both ID property is 0.

why it happened? and how can I set object data with right ID?

Comment: Can you post class structure for `myObj`?

Comment: @Arindam Nayak ahhhhh! it becaused protected set;. Thank you!